# Syntax error while creating view for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My query:

```
CREATE VIEW SOME_VIEW2 AS 
(
  SELECT to_char(tbl_albums.album), COUNT(tbl_songs.id) AS "Songs in album"
  FROM tbl_songs 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_albums 
  ON tbl_songs.album_id = tbl_albums.id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_bands
  ON tbl_albums.band_id = tbl_bands.id
  WHERE to_char(LOWER(TRIM(tbl_bands.band))) = 'metallica'
  GROUP BY to_char(tbl_albums.album)
);
```

Error I got:

> Error at Command Line:10 Column:12 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00998:
>   must name this expression with a column alias
>   00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"

This doesn't work, however I previously tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW SOME_VIEW AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM tbl_albums
);
```

And this worked fine, want to ask, what is wrong with first query.

Comment: Give an alias to the column `to_char(tbl_albums.album)` in your select list.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for the parentheses around the actual select statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All columns must be named in a view.  Since you have a calculated column, i.e.

```
to_char(tbl_albums.album)
```

You need to give it a name, like so:

```
to_char(tbl_albums.album) "Album"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query :

```
CREATE VIEW SOME_VIEW2 (album , SongsInAlbum) AS 
(
  SELECT q.alb,q.counter FROM
  (SELECT to_char(tbl_albums.album) as alb, rownum as counter
  FROM tbl_songs 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_albums 
  ON tbl_songs.album_id = tbl_albums.id
  LEFT JOIN tbl_bands
  ON tbl_albums.band_id = tbl_bands.id
  WHERE to_char(LOWER(TRIM(tbl_bands.band))) = 'metallica')q
);
```